# Get result with inner join and group by in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linqpad

I am struggling to group by, basically I need to get list of all Teachers and the total number of students they are responsible for across all of their classes. I need to use Linq expression

here is ER diagram 
[image]

### LINQ

```
from _teacher in Teachers
join _class in Classes on _teacher.Id equals _class.TeacherId 
join _studentClasses in StudentClasses on _class.Id equals _studentClasses.ClassId 
group _studentClasses by _studentClasses.StudentId into _grouped 
select new {_teacher, _class.Name, _studentClasses.StudentId}
```

Comment: select new {_teacher, _class.Name, _studentClasses.StudentId} says "does not exist in current context"

Comment: I need to pull out teacher names and count of students they are teaching for each class!

Comment: did the answar by @Arion help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the columns you have grouped by. So I think you can do something like this:

```
from _teacher in Teachers
join _class in Classes 
    on _teacher.Id equals _class.TeacherId 
join _studentClasses in StudentClasses 
    on _class.Id equals _studentClasses.ClassId 
group _studentClasses by 
new
{
   TeacherName=__teacher.Name,
   ClassName=_class.Name
} 
into _grouped 
select new 
{
    _grouped.Key.TeacherName, 
    _grouped.Key.ClassName, 
    stundetCount=_grouped.Count()
}
```